# Backbone.js and Django Rest Framework registration and authentication

Tags: javascript, django, backbone.js, django-rest-framework

I am creating an app using backbone.js for my frontend, and django-rest-framework for my backend. I want to be able to register users, log in and out users, and check if users are logged in with backbone.

I understand how the django authentication works and how drf uses authentication, but I have no idea how I can tie it into backbone.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean "tie it into backbone"? You can access `request.user` in javascript and `request.is_authenticated` too.

Comment: I think this is one of those "Not sure what to ask" questions. If I have a model in backbone, based on a drf endpoint like 'urlRoot: /model', I can call .save to post it to drf, or .delete to delete it, but it is not like that with users right? How would a backbone view register a user, or log a user in? Thanks for the advice though, I will keep looking in to this.

Comment: I have never used backbone to register users or to log them in. I thought all you wanted is to interact with `request.user`. However, I believe it wouuld be wise to take advantage of Django authentication system and then use Backbone for the other interactions.

Comment: Yes, I would like to use the Django authentication system, but how do I write backbone views to create a User and log in or log out. Sorry if my question is confusing. I am very new to all of this.

Comment: So.. what I'd do is use an html template with a regular form that logs the user in. Then if the login is succesful, redirect the user to the Backbone-powered one-page app. To register the user I'd do the same, a regular html form, no Backbone. I use Backbone for other interactions.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. Seems there is no easy way to handle login and registration using django auth from the single page app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of your app is only accessible with user password, use Django's authentication system https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.login. Make all your views @login_required.

Now if you want to log them in via an ajax call, create a view as follows:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def login_ajax(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
    user = authenticate(username=data['user'], password=data['pass'])
    if user:      
        return HttpResponse("OK")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Error", status=401)
```

Later, on your JS on your template:

```
$.post( /* url where you mapped the login_ajax view */, { user: "John", pass: "abc123" } )
 .done(function( data ) { alert( "User logged in: " + data );})
 .fail(function( data ) { alert( "User not logged in: " + data );});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [django-rest-auth](http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) with AngularJS. It provides you a set of REST API endpoints to handle User Registration and Authentication tasks and it integrates perfectly with [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth).

To get users information, you need to call this API:

```
.../rest-auth/user/
```

By default the response is:

```
username
first_name
last_name
email
```

But you can extend it with other informations.